# Canvas looking stretched when modifying ImageData

Tags: javascript, canvas, getimagedata, putimagedata, imagedata

I'm trying to port one of my Processing projects (see [Github page for the project](https://github.com/Hayden977/StemProject)) into vanilla Javascript but I'm having issues "transplanting" the data from one ImageData object into another ImageData object. I can fill an area of the canvas with a rectangle of color just fine, but for some reason the same does not work with images.

Here is the code I use to place an area of ImageData into another area of image data.

```
image(ix, iy, iw, ih, i) {
    let xMin = ix;
    let xMax = ix + iw;
    let yMin = iy;
    let yMax = iy + ih;
    if (xMin < 0) xMin = 0;
    if (xMax > this.w) xMax = this.w;
    if (yMin < 0) yMin = 0;
    if (yMax > this.h) yMax = this.h;
    let data = this.buffer.data;
    let im_data = i.buffer.data;
    for (let x = xMin; x < xMax; x++) {
        for (let y = yMin; y < yMax; y++) {
            let i_x_off = x - ix;
            let i_y_off = y - iy;
            let ind = this.index(x, y);
            let i_ind = this.index(i_x_off, i_y_off);
            data[ind + 0] = im_data[i_ind + 0];
            data[ind + 1] = im_data[i_ind + 1];
            data[ind + 2] = im_data[i_ind + 2];
            data[ind + 3] = im_data[i_ind + 3];
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function I am using to get the index into the ImageData from an x and y value

```
index(x, y) {
    return y * (this.w * 4) + (x * 4);
}
```

And here is the function I have been using to put rectangles onto the canvas. Notice how similar it is to the `image()` function

```
rect(rx, ry, rw, rh, c) {
        let xMin = rx;
        let xMax = rx + rw;
        let yMin = ry;
        let yMax = ry + rh;
        if (xMin < 0) xMin = 0;
        if (xMax > this.w) xMax = this.w;
        if (yMin < 0) yMin = 0;
        if (yMax > this.h) yMax = this.w;
        let data = this.buffer.data;
        for (let x = xMin; x < xMax; x++) {
            for (let y = yMin; y < yMax; y++) {
                let i = this.index(x, y);
                data[i + 0] = c.r;
                data[i + 1] = c.b;
                data[i + 2] = c.g;
                data[i + 3] = c.a;
            }
        }
    }
```

**There isn't really a way to show the problem without an image, so here is an image of the canvas with an image of the Godot logo. (This is the stretching I am talking about).
[Image of HTML5 canvas with Godot logo bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW5pX.png)**
(Here is a reference for what the source image looks like). [Godot logo from Twitter](https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/911512672830738432/wZXPJXx__400x400.jpg)

In terms of the order the functions are executed in, see below.

```
const main = () => {
            raw.flush(); // Setting all the "pixels" to RGBA 0, 0, 0, 0
            raw.rect(10, 10, im.w, im.h, color());
            raw.image(10, 10, im.w, im.h, im);
            GLOBALCANVASCONTEXT.putImageData(raw.buffer, 0, 0); // The buffer is just another name for the result of ctx.createImageData(w, h)
            window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
        };
```

Comment: Didn't try to compile your code but at a glance I'd say `let i_ind = this.index(i_x_off, i_y_off);` should be `let i_ind = i.index(i_x_off, i_y_off);` at least if both your instances don't share the same `.w` property value. Also, you should really consider using an Uint32Array view over your ImageDatas' buffer so you can set a full pixel in a single operation.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. You'll be linked in the support section :)